# How to run embedding lookup layer on CPU

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras, inference

I have a pre-trained tensorflow model exported with keras saved model format. When I used this model for inference, the embedding lookup is executed on GPU. I wonder if there is a way to move the embedding lookup to CPU for better performance.

1. The following is the python function defined for inference.
   **Related code snippet:
   **

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 50), dtype=tf.int64, name="user_fea1"),
                              tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 50), dtype=tf.int64, name="user_fea2"),
                              tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 50), dtype=tf.int64, name="user_fea3"),
                              tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.float32)])
    def nann_server(self, input_1, input_2, input_3, item_emb):
        # want this part to run on CPU 
        user_feat = [input_1, input_2, input_3]
        mask = (user_feat[0] >= 0)
        item_list = self.item_id_embedding(tf.where(mask, user_feat[0], 0))
        shop_list = self.shop_id_embedding(tf.where(mask, user_feat[1], 0))
        cat1_list = self.cat1_embedding(tf.where(mask, user_feat[2], 0))
        user_emb = tf.concat([item_list, shop_list, cat1_list], -1)

        # want the following part to run on GPU
        item_emb = tf.expand_dims(item_emb, axis=1)
        att_out = self.nonlinear_attention(item_emb, user_emb, user_emb)
        att_out = tf.reduce_sum(att_out, axis=-2)
        mlp_layer = tf.concat([att_out, item_emb], axis=-1)
        mlp_layer = self.bn1(self.nn_fc1(mlp_layer))
        mlp_layer = tf.nn.selu(mlp_layer)
        mlp_layer = self.bn2(self.nn_fc2(mlp_layer))
        mlp_layer = tf.nn.selu(mlp_layer)
        mlp_layer = self.nn_fc3(mlp_layer)
        logits = tf.nn.sigmoid(mlp_layer)
        logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 1])

        return logits
```

2. I modified related op running device by loading the original saved_model.pb and saved to a new saved_model.pb. Op running device modification code is as follows:

```
cpu_device = "/device:CPU:0"

target_nodes = {
   "mlp_model_v0/embedding/embeddings",
   "mlp_model_v0/embedding/embeddings/Read/ReadVariableOp",
   "mlp_model_v0/embedding_1/embeddings",
   "mlp_model_v0/embedding_1/embeddings/Read/ReadVariableOp",
   "mlp_model_v0/embedding_2/embeddings",
   "mlp_model_v0/embedding_2/embeddings/Read/ReadVariableOp",
   "mlp_model_v0/embedding_3/embeddings",
   "mlp_model_v0/embedding_3/embeddings/Read/ReadVariableOp",
   "serving_default_item_emb",
   "serving_default_user_fea1",
   "serving_default_user_fea2",
   "serving_default_user_fea3"
}

model_name = "mlp_model_v0"
emb = "embedding"
emb_1 = "embedding_1"
emb_2 = "embedding_2"
emb_3 = "embedding_3"

def load(path):

    graph_path = Path(path, "raw_saved_model.pb")
    sm = SavedModel()
    with graph_path.open('rb') as f:
        sm.ParseFromString(f.read())
    for mg in sm.meta_graphs:
        for node in mg.graph_def.node:
            if node.name in target_nodes:
                node.device = cpu_device
                print("name="+node.name+",op="+node.op+",device="+node.device)

        for func in mg.graph_def.library.function:
            for node in func.node_def:
                nameSplit = node.name.split('/')
                if len(nameSplit) >= 2 and nameSplit[0] == model_name and \
                        (nameSplit[1] == emb_1 or nameSplit[1] == emb_2 or \
                         nameSplit[1] == emb_3):
                    node.device = cpu_device
                    print("name="+node.name+",op="+node.op+",device="+node.device)
                    #for res in result:
                    #    print("matched = "+res+", node name = "+node.name)

    converted_graph_path = Path(path, "saved_model.pb")
    with converted_graph_path.open('wb') as f:
        f.write(sm.SerializeToString())
```

But errors like `indices[4, 0] = 20011 is not in [0, 1000)` occurs.

3. Environments
   System Version: Ubuntu 16.04.6
   Tensorflow Version: tensorflow-gpu 2.8.0
   Python: 3.7